# How to take values from interface

Tags: c#, interface

i have an interface like this ,

```
 public interface IResourcePolicy
   {
      string AgentVersion
      {
         get;
         set;
      }
      ResourcePolicy ResourcePolicy
      {
         get;
         set;
      }
   }
// implementation of AgentVersion only as of now i am showing
        public string AgentVersion
        {
            get
            {
                return m_agentVersion;
            }
            set
            {
                m_agentVersion = value;
            }
        }
        private string m_agentVersion = null;
```

in the following code i need to check one more codition like that if m_agentVersion != null 
& ResourcePolicy = null i need to display m_nullPolicy rather than m_nullString,this is the exisitng code

```
public class ResourcePolicyConverter : StringConverter
   {
        private static string m_nullString = Managers.ControlStrings.GetString("ManagedDeviceWizard.None");
          private static string m_nullPolicy = Managers.ControlStrings.GetString("ManagedDeviceWizard.UnknownPolicy");
       if( value is ResourcePolicy )
                {
                   return ((ResourcePolicy)value).Identifier;
                }
                else if( value == null )
                {
                   return m_nullString;
                }}
```

How will i achieve this

Comment: Please ppl write why you downvote. Especialy when it's new people to let them know why!

Comment: I think you want to use `abstract class` and `interface` to do this. Abstract class will implement interface and check its values, and other class will only inherit abstract class... and therefore implement interface.

Comment: @Cipi, write it as an answer ;)

Comment: What my intention is to get a valu from interface implementation side and check that value in different class ,based on the codition display m_nullPolicy,, Cant we do like that without concept of abstract

Comment: don't think you can, an interface has no implementation by itself

Comment: -1: I've read this question several times (including comments), and still have no idea what the asker is trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

An interface is used only as a "Must be like that" and everything must stay unvariant. So it's impossible.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dyc5b94e(v=vs.71).aspx) as a complete explanation of what is an interface.

As @Cipi said as a comment on your main question, you may have to use an Abstract class instead ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/sf985hc5(v=vs.80).aspx))

```
abstract class AgentVersionBase {
    public string AgentVersion {
        get {
            return m_agentVersion;
        }
    }
    private string m_agentVersion = string.Empty;
}
public class AgentVersion : AgentVersionBase {
    public string aMethod() {
        return base.AgentVersion;
    }
}
```

Note : Sorry for my english, I'm usualy talking french

Comment: so from interface IResourcePolicy can i take value by using abstract class

Comment: Put all this code into AgentVersion. Then, ``AnotherClass``will inherits of it so you will use him as ``base.WhatYouWant``.

Comment: You **can't** add code into an interface at all. It's only a "Skeleton" of what you want.

Comment: That's what I were goin to add into my exemple hehe.

Comment: i am getting  errors, based on my question code can you suggest where i can put your code

Comment: Give me few minutes I'll try something

Comment: What the exact meaning about StringConverter. I can't find how to use it. How you use it exactly

Comment: it is System.ComponentModel.StringConverter, i am displaying the value in propertygrid, in UI i have fixed code but in property grid when i want to display ManagedDeviceWizard.UnknownPolicy i am getting ManagedDeviceWizard.None

Comment: Please edit your ResourcePolicyConvert to make it work because a `If` clause directly into a class won't work.

Comment: i didnt get u,first up all can you tell me where i can put your code,do ineed to create seperatley and inherit interface

Comment: Forget the interface and simply replace it with my code. After that, I didn't get you anymore though. I have to know how you use ResourcePolicyConverter but I didn't get it

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use abstract class and interface to do this. Abstract class will implement interface and check its values, and other class will only inherit abstract class... and therefore implement interface.

Comment: It is great to add one/few exemple to your answer in order to help him out a litle bit.